# Where can I find more insight about spaces of subsets of a base space?

Tags: general-topology, uniform-spaces, continuum-theory

I've been studying Michael's article "Topologies on spaces of subsets" and he states some propositions and lemmas without proving, asserting that they follow directly from the definitions but sometimes I struggle to prove them. I would like to know if there is any book that have a discussion about Vietoris topology and uniform topology on collections of subsets of a base space, hyperspaces being an example of such thing.

I found the book Hyperspaces Fundamentals and Recent Advances by Alejandro Illanes and Sam Nadler but it is focused in hyperspaces, and I'd like something more general. I've seen that some books of topology or uniformities have a quick discussion about it but still I want (and think I need) more.

Comment: Michael himself gives Bourbaki as a reference for the uniform structure on $2^X$ and I suspect this is not studied in many other places, since people often look at $2^X$ for compact $X$, which makes $2^X$ itself compact and thus there is a unique compatible uniformity

Comment: @AlessandroCodenotti True, but e.g. $2^{\Bbb N}$ is an interesting example of a natural Tychonoff non-normal space. So I quite like general hyperspaces.

Comment: @Henno Brandsma: I checked my file of dissertations, sorted by topic (obtained as I come across them, either by specific search or by accident), and of possible interest to you is: William Joseph Stager, [**Construction and Properties of Hyper-Quasi-Uniformities on the Hyperspace**](https://etd.ohiolink.edu/apexprod/rws_olink/r/1501/10?clear=10&p10_accession_num=osu1486661273545455), Ph.D. Dissertation (under Norman Levine), Ohio State Univ., 1970, iv + 85 pages. In it the prefixes "pseudo" and "quasi" are used as in Čech's 1966 [**Topological Spaces**](https://eudml.org/doc/277000).

Comment: Oops, ignore the comment about Čech's book. I was thinking the usage was not what's current, but I think both Stager and Čech use current meanings (for generalized metric spaces: pseudo -- different points can have zero distance; quasi -- symmetry doesn't have to hold; semi -- triangle inequality doesn't have to hold).

Comment: @AlessandroCodenotti yeah, I have checked Bourbaki but honestly the only thing I found about this was an exercise, the exercise Michael mentions in a definition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I propose that you take individual issues from that paper (that I know quite well, as we did a special seminar on it in Uni and I've later studied hyperspaces for my PhD), post them as questions on the site and your thoughts on their proof as well, and see if the community can answer them for you.

The book by Nadler (and this later followup) are quite good I found, there is also a book by Beer (IIRC) with Elsevier publishers on hyperspace topologies. The Vietoris topology isn't the only one (though it's quite an interesting one and the default for me as well).

I'd say, post questions and open the discussion. I personally found all the "it's easily seen"-statements by Michael indeed quite easy in the end.

My 2 cts..

Comment: From my bookshelves: [**Hyperspaces of Sets**](https://www.amazon.com/dp/0824767683) by Nadler (1978), [**Continuum Theory**](https://www.amazon.com/dp/0824786599) by Nadler (1992), [**Topologies on Closed and Closed Convex Sets**](https://www.amazon.com/dp/9048143330) by Beer (1993). Marginally related, and more for real analysis perspectives rather than general topological or convex geometrical perspectives, is [**Hausdorff Approximations**](https://www.amazon.com/dp/9401067872) by Sendov (1990 English translation edited by Beer).

Comment: A survey paper of possible interest is *Hyperspaces and multifunctions, the first half century (1900 - 1950)* by Byron L. McAllister [**Nieuw Archief voor Wiskunde** (3) 26, 1978, pp. 309-329]. Unfortunately, this paper doesn't appear to be online.

Comment: I stumbled upon this book by Beer one day but then I totally forgot of it! Seems like I can find more things about Vietoris topology there, I will take a look and think more about what I'm struggling to prove, then I'll post here. The seminar you mentioned must have been amazing! I get really excited about this paper, it seems so interesting.

Comment: @Bryant I’m a fan of the different selection theorems that Michael and others proved, and the connection with different covering properties etc. A whole series of papers.

Comment: *fan of the different selection theorems* --- [**Selectors**](https://www.amazon.com/dp/0691096287) by Jayne/Rogers (2002). I assume you know about this book, but since I mentioned all those others . . .